Proving $\int_0^1\frac{x^{b-1}}{1+x}dx=\psi(b)-\psi\left(\frac b2\right)-\log(2)$
Below is an integral that was sent to me along with the solution. Here is my attempt, I will show where exactly I am stuck:
$$\int_0^1\frac{x^{b-1}}{1+x}dx=\psi(b)-\psi\left(\frac b2\right)-\log(2)$$
I should mention that $b\in\Bbb{R}$ and $b>0$. I will begin by mentioning the series definition of the gamma function: $$\psi(x)=-\gamma+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left( \frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{n+x} \right)$$
Then I rewrote the integral and changed the order of the integral and sum:
$$\int_0^1\frac{x^{b-1}}{1+x}dx=\int_0^1\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}\frac{1}{n+b-1}$$
$$=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1} \int_0^1x^{b+n-2}dx=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}\frac{1}{n+b-1}$$
From here we rearrange the sum, considering $n$ odd and even
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left( \frac{1}{2n+b-2}-\frac{1}{2n+b-1} \right)$$
I add and subtract $\frac{1}{2n}$ under the sum
$$\frac12\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left( \frac1n -\frac{1}{n+\frac{b-1}{2}}-\left( \frac1n -\frac{1}{n+\frac{b-2}{2}} \right)\right)$$
$$\frac12\left[ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left( \frac1n -\frac{1}{n+\frac{b-1}{2}}\right)-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left( \frac1n -\frac{1}{n+\frac{b-2}{2}} \right)\right]$$
Reindexing both starting from $n=0$:
$$\frac12\left[\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left( \frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{n+\frac{1+b}{2}}\right)-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left( \frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{n+\frac b2} \right)  \right]$$
Now I employ the series representation used above:
$$\frac12\left( \psi\left( \frac{1+b}{2} \right)-\psi\left( \frac b2 \right) \right)$$
I have solved the integral but don't understand how it is simplified to the final form that is in the title and the beginning of my post.
I found this question on SE, but it merely discusses the convergence on the interval $[0,\infty)$. I am looking for any potential methods to convert my answer to the solution provided.

You can transform $\frac12\left( \psi\left( \frac{1+b}{2} \right)-\psi\left( \frac b2 \right) \right)$ to $\psi(2)-\psi\left( \frac b2 \right)-\log(2)$ using the Digamma function's multiplication theorem:
$$\psi(nz)=\frac1n\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\psi\left( z+\frac kn \right)+\ln n$$
Upon replacing $z$ with $\frac b2$ we obtain:
$$\psi(b)=\frac12\psi\left(\frac s2\right)+\frac12\psi\left(\frac{1+b}{2}\right)+\log(2)$$
Wish it helps.

Using the Duplication Formula of Digamma Function:
$$
2 \psi(2x)=2 \ln 2+\psi(x)+\psi\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)
$$
and replacing $x$ by $\frac{b}{2}$ yields $$
\psi(b)=\ln 2+\frac{1}{2} \psi\left(\frac{b}{2}\right)+\frac{1}{2} \psi\left(\frac{b+1}{2}\right)
$$
Plugging back gives
$$
I=\frac{1}{2}\left[\psi\left(\frac{b+1}{2}\right)-\psi\left(\frac{b}{2}\right) \right]=\psi(b)-\psi\left(\frac{b}{2}\right)-\ln 2
$$
